# printf in bash function add new line to the `wc -l` results

Tags: bash, printf

With `wc` I get in one line number of lines then the file name:

```
$ wc -l ./lpm/modelisator.py
426 ./lpm/modelisator.py
$
```

I try to do a printf formating:

```
$ do_stuff() { printf "lines: %s\n" `wc -l $1` ;}
$
$ do_stuff ./lpm/modelisator.py
lines: 426
lines: ./lpm/modelisator.py
$
```

I whould like to understand why I get this two lines:

BTW using file as stdin I get what I want:

```
$ do_stuff() { printf "lines: %s\n" `cat $1 |wc -l` ;} 
$ do_stuff ./lpm/modelisator.py
lines: 426
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `wc -l filename`, it outputs filename next to the number of lines in it. And when a command substitution is not wrapped in double-quotes, it undergoes word-splitting, i.e expands to multiple words if it has any spaces in it. And, lastly, `printf` uses the format over and over until it consumes all given arguments.

Like, let's say `file` has 10 lines in it, then

```
printf 'lines: %s\n' `wc -l file`
```

is the same as

```
printf 'lines: %s\nlines: %s\n' '10' 'file'
```

So, do it like this instead:

```
printf 'lines: %s\n' "$(wc -l <"$1")"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `\n` with `<space>` or `\t`

E.g.:

```sh
## <space> as delimiter
do_stuff() { printf "lines: %s " `wc -l $1` ;} 

## <tab> as delimiter
do_stuff() { printf "lines: %s\t" `wc -l $1` ;}
```